# Bootstrap4, JQuery3 and FOS Comment Bundle => $.get(...).error is not a function

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony3.x, jquery-3, foscommentbundle

This is more a fix I found rather than a question.

On a Symfony 3 project, I decided to upgrade to bootstrap 3 to 4. It implied using JQuery3 which is not fully compatible with the asynchronous comments display of Fos Comment Bundle 2.0.14 (and probably earlier).

You'll probably get a JS error:

**TypeError:$.get(...).error is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the '.error' called in the js is deprecated in jQuery3 (see at the bottom of https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/).

To correct this cleanly, without modifying the bundle files:

**STEP1:**

copy the file

> web/bundles/foscomment/js/comment.js

to

> web/js/foscomments-fix-jquery-3.js

(or whatever name you want)

**STEP 2:**

update the lines

```
$.post(url, data, success).error(wrappedErrorCallback).complete(wrappedCompleteCallback);
```

to

```
$.post(url, data, success).fail(wrappedErrorCallback).done(wrappedCompleteCallback);
```

and

```
$.get(url, data, success).error(wrappedErrorCallback);
```

to

```
$.get(url, data, success).fail(wrappedErrorCallback);
```

**STEP 3:**

copy

> vendor/friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle/FOS/CommentBundle/Resources/views/Thread/async.html.twig

to

> app/Resources/FOSCommentBundle/views/Thread/async.html.twig

**STEP 4:**

modify the line

```
fos_comment_script.src = '{{ asset('bundles/foscomment/js/comments.js') }}';
```

like this:

```
fos_comment_script.src = '{{ asset('**js/foscomments-fix-jquery-3.js**') }}';
```